# Streaming two phones' cameras to google cardboard

Tags: android, camera, google-cardboard

I'm planning to put two android smartphones side to side then streaming their cameras to a third smartphone which will display both streams at once. I'll then use google cardboard to view the two streams as one.

While video quality isn't an issue, having very low lag and not requiring an internet connection would be great, which leave wifi, bluetooth and cable connection as the main candidates.

I'd like to know how you'd tackle this project, plus any advice/resource would be helpful (since i'm a newbie when it comes to android). The main difficulty is streaming from two devices at once.

One thing to keep in mind is that i plan to use no other features regarding VR and google cardboard, so all i need is to display both streams side by side, nothing else.

Comment: If this is just some proof of concept, you could stream the phones to a pc with [obs](https://obsproject.com/) and stream the computer screen (with the other streams showing) to the phone in the cardboard.

Comment: Well the idea was to have the phones work without other devices in between, without being limited to one particuliar place, so that'd be a last ditch solution at best. At that point i could use apps akin to 'ip webcam' and put 2 browsers side by side on my google cardboard's phone.